# Optaplanner SwapMove filter in Cheap Time

Tags: optaplanner

I working on a new Planning problem and are using Cheap Time for testing. I want to add a filter to handle a Hard Score constraint. In some cases, a machine cannot be assigned - at all.

I added this filter SwapMove filter:

```
public class TaskAssignmentFilter implements SelectionFilter<SwapMove> {

public boolean accept(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, SwapMove move) {
TaskAssignment task1 = (TaskAssignment)move.getLeftEntity();
    TaskAssignment task2 = (TaskAssignment)move.getRightEntity();

    if (task1.getMachine().getIndex() == 0 || task2.getMachine().getIndex() == 0)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

}

And added to the config

```
<swapMoveSelector>
    <filterClass>….TaskAssignmentFilter</filterClass>
</swapMoveSelector>
```

However, machine index 0 is still assigned.

Any hint to what I am doing wrong?

And is it possible to handle that constraint this in the Score Calculator also?

Comment: I wouldn't use filters to accomplish that. I 'd just add a hard constraint in the score rules (= score calculator) instead. If you do intend to use filters, know that you need to apply them on every move selector, both those in the CH and the LS.

Comment: [Docs adjusted](http://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/commit/fcb611e4e)

Comment: It worked I just added one more Hard Constraint and had to use BendableLongScore

Comment: By the way how is each hard constraint inside a BendableLongScore weighted by the planner/solver?. Equally important?

Comment: No, in that case you'd just use HardSoftLongScore. See docs on score levels vs score weights.